# parse issue "Unexpected '@' in program"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Xcode gives following error, I searched a lot but could not get right answer

**My code**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LocateViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "constant.h"

@interface AcceptJobViewController : UIViewController<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MBProgressHUDDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteBgView;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrlView;
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    BOOL isClicked1;
    UIPickerView *pktStatePicker ;
    UIToolbar *mypickerToolbar;

    IBOutlet UIButton *vacantBtn;
    UITableView *btnwttime;

    NSString *StatusStrnig;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn_telephone,*btn_call,*btn_equry,*btn_thanks,*btn_inform,*btn_navigate1,*btn_navigat2e2,*btn_navigate3 ,*btn_navigate4,*btn_navigate5,*btn_navigate6,*btn_complete,*btn_Cancel,*btn_route,*btn_noshow;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFare;
    int dispatch;
    NSMutableArray *arrList;
    NSArray *wt_array;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *environment;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *resultText;


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *close;

@property (nonatomic,retain)    CLLocationManager *lm;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *passedArrray;
-(IBAction)backBtnClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)homeBtnClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)callClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)telephoneClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)msgClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)navigateAClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)navigateBClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)navigateCClick:(id)sender;
//-(IBAction)jobCompleteClick:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)jobCancelClick:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)btn_make_payment:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btn_thanks_sms:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btn_enquire_sms:(id)sender;

//-(IBAction)Vacant:(id)sender;
@end
```

[image]

Now please check my header file as above. It gives errors of

1) "Unexpected '@' in program"

2) Missing context for method declration of IBAction

Comment: Is the file recognized by Xcode as Objective-C or C?

Comment: Please take a screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqUF.png) and add to the question.

Comment: Why are all of those ivars being declared in the .h file? Why are you putting all of those protocols in the .h file? None of that stuff belongs in the public header file. All of that should be moved to the .m file. Just leave the public properties and public methods in the .h file.

Comment: Did you tried to perform a Clean? Maybe it's an Xcode issue.

Answer (score 0):

please be sure you declare your both variable like

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
//Before @end
//Right
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString * environment;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString * resultText;

@end

//If outside then get error like you got
//Wrong
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString * environment;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString * resultText;
```

Comment: i create one demo same as you created in this code but i don't get any error like this